# I want to add spinner on listview row which I have in my application

Tags: android

I'm a Fresher to android.

I have a Listview and inside that Listview row I need 2 to 3 spinners.

Eg:

Inside that listview row I need to display the country list (spinner1),state list (spinner2) and city list (spinner3). Each of the three lists should be displayed in separate spinner.

Actually I have created a listview but I don't have any idea about inserting spinner inside the ListView row.

This is my listview code:

```
public void downloadBtnSelected(View anchor) {
// Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
hm.put("Menu", Menu[i]);

hm.put("Images", Integer.toString(Images[i]) );
aList.add(hm);
}

// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = { "Images","Menu" };

// Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = { R.id.imageView1,R.id.textView1};

// Instantiating an adapter to store each items
// R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

// Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

// Setting the adapter to the listView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can anyone please orient me with a best way?

Comment: Here try this site http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: Use Custom ListView..and custom Rows.

Comment: Ok thanks Let me give a try